# How to save Hex value characters from char array elements to a char array, TCHAR, LPCTSTR, and CString?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, hex, mfc-feature-pack

How to I take the byte hex values from each element, and save each hex character to a char array, TCHAR, LPCTSTR, and CString?

Yes, I know that some of these are close to or functionally the same thing, but I have to save and manipulate the data a few different ways and will need these datatypes. If that make this a little too broad, for the sake of limiting this question to my immediate purposes, one of my needs is to take packet data I collected to a char array and output it as Hex to a List on my MFC application (`SetItemText(int, int, LPCTSTR)`).  But I imagine much of the process is similar or the same, and I would appreciate the help with the other datatypes.

I have search around and tried several methods involving `stringstream`[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723403/char-array-to-hex-string-c) , `sprintf` [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7928711/convert-byte-array-char-array-to-hexidecimal-string-in-c) , and a few others.  The most I was able to output was the data array's memory location (not the data itself).  The rest resulted in garbage characters, nothing, or the wrong data... and even then, the >10 zeros were not present.  I'm sure the error is with my implementation, so I'm here for a focused use case.  Below is a framework of what I'm looking for.

```
void SaveCharArrayHexData(struct &output, int index)
{
    char data[4] = {'0x07', '0x13', '0xF4', '\0'};

    //Get byte hex values from data
    //Assign each Hex character to datatypes as individual characters, including >10 zeros.
    //Example: 
    //        INPUT: data={'0x07', '0x13', '0xF4', '\0'}  size = 3
    //       OUTPUT: outputCharArray={'0', '7', '1', '3', 'F', '4', '\0'}  size = 6

    //output.outputCharArray = ?
    //output.outputLPCTSTR = ?
    //output.outputTCHAR = ?
    //output.outputCString = ?

    m_list.SetItemText(index, 0, outputLPCTSTR);

}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a hex value. Hex is a representation. Those bytes contain binary.

Comment: What I want is to turn that representation into a value.  I'll correct to be clear.

Comment: **The most I was able to output was...** Show your attempt in the question. What you have posted, is an invlalid code.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure I even got your question right; it seems... too trivial.

I usually avoid sprintf and streams and whatnot for such trivial tasks.

To convert a single char to two hex characters, just do something like this:

```
char hexDigit(unsigned char value)
{
   if (value<=9) return '0'+value;
   assert(value<=15);
   return 'a'-10+value;
}

void toHex(char input, std::string& output)
{
   output+=hexDigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(input)>>4);
   output+=hexDigit(input&0x0f);
}
```

Note: this only works on computers that use ASCII-based character encodings. Or 100% of the machines you'll encounter these days, unless you're doing software for old mainframes that might still be using EBCDIC. Alternative version:

```
char hexDigit(unsigned char value)
{
   assert(value<=15);
   return "0123456789abcdef"[value];
}
```

`toHex()` just appends the two digits to the output string. You can do something like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

// code from above goes here

int main(void)
{
    char data[] = {0x07, 0x13, 0xF4};
    std::string result;
    for (char c: data)
    {
        if (!result.empty()) result+=", ";
        toHex(c, result);
    }
    std::cout << result << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Test run:

```
stieber@gatekeeper:~ $ g++ Test.cpp && ./a.out
07, 13, f4
```

Adapt the general idea to whatever datatypes you actually want to use.

Comment: Side issue: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. Use `'\n'` to end a line unless there’s a good reason not to.

Comment: Yeah... old habit. I rarely output anything to a stream that's not a log line :-)

Comment: @ChristianStieber  Yes, super trivial.  I'm returning to coding since school 6-7 years ago, so I'm re-learning a lot.  None of the answers after hours of Googling around seemed to point me in the right direction.  Any time it was close, the post leading to an answer was stifled by community snark.  So I appreciate you taking the time.  It looks like the answer.  I just have to flesh it out to my specific needs.  

I'm still outputting some weird characters after the first few bytes that are correctly outputting. It's likely an issue with 'char data', so I have to work backwards a bit to see.

Comment: @ChristianStieber -- `std::clog` is unit buffered, so every insertion ends with a flush; as the name suggests, it's intended for logging.

Answer (score 0):

The links you referenced are solving the task.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
  unsigned char data[4] = {0x07, 0x13, 0xF4, 0};
  std::stringstream ss;

  // This is all what you need.
  std::copy(std::begin(data), std::prev(std::end(data)),
            std::ostream_iterator<int>(ss << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2)
                                          << std::hex));

  const auto& outputCharArray = ss.str();
  std::cout << outputCharArray << "\n";
  std::cout << "size: " << outputCharArray.size() << "\n";
}
// 0713f4
// size: 6
```

Known issue:

```
unsigned char data[4] = {0x07, 0x03, 0xF4, 0};
// 073f4
// size: 5
```

fixed here ["Permanent" std::setw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405039/permanent-stdsetw) or with using a range loop.